# How to set checked="checked" in first radio button?

Tags: php

How to set checked="checked" in first radio button ?

i use this code but checked="checked" in last radio button , i want to checked="checked" in first radio button.

```
<?
include("connect.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>


<ul style="height: 150px; ">
<?
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
?>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input checked="checked" name="time" style="border: none" type="radio" value="<?=$objResult["month"];?>">
              <?=$objResult["month"];?>
            </label>
          </li>
<?
}
?>
</ul>
<?
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: Actually, you are checking all inputs, but logically only last gets checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write `checked="checked"` once using an `if` control

```
<?
$checked = 'checked="checked"';
$firstTime = true;
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
?>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input 
                <? if ($firstTime) echo $chekced; ?> 
                name="time" 
                style="border: none" 
                type="radio" 
                value="<?=$objResult["month"];?>" />

                <?=$objResult["month"];?>
            </label>
       </li>
<?
    $firstTime = false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the code buddy:

```
<?
include("connect.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>


<ul style="height: 150px; ">
<?
$cnt=1; 
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $checked = ($cnt == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input <?php echo $checked ?> name="time" style="border: none" type="radio" value="<?=$objResult["month"];?>">
              <?=$objResult["month"];?>
            </label>
          </li>
<?
$cnt++;
}
?>
</ul>
<?
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: should not it be `$checked = ($cnt == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to count your loop and add the attribute is it is the first one

```
$i = 0; 
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {    
?>
      <li>
        <label> 
<?php if($i == 0) { ?> 
          <input checked="checked" name="time" style="border: none" type="radio" value="<?=$objResult["month"];?>">
<?php  } else { ?>
          <input name="time" style="border: none" type="radio" value="<?=$objResult["month"];?>">
<?php  } ?>          
           <?=$objResult["month"];?>
        </label>
      </li>
<?
    $i++; 
 }
```